# How can I set an custom icon for my app made for IOS on codename one

Tags: ios, icons, codenameone

Hello there am trying to set up a custom icon for my IOS app. Am using the option for setting up the icon given on the properties section. Each time I upload a png image it keeps rejecting it and asking for image with dimension of 512 x 512. The image I keep trying to upload is of that size. But is still wont take it. Is there a way of fixing this?

[image: Error on selecting 512 X 512 png picture]

Comment: What format is your image in? I would format it as a PNG.

Comment: It is a PNG image as I have mentioned in the question.

Answer (score 2):

Make sure the image is 512x512 exactly and in PNG format.

Comment: I did and it eventually worked. Thank you for the help.

Answer (score 0):

Very strange. You'd like to be care of 2 things following:

1. PNG format and 512 x 512 size exactly.
2. Make sure the file extension is uppercase, such like "icon.PNG".

I was very surprised by this uppercase extension issue.
Good luck~!